# Background processes in bash preserving order

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, background-process, concurrency

From a GUI terminal emulator running `bash`, I would like to open a [`tabbed`](http://tools.suckless.org/tabbed/) instance, get its [X window ID](https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/X/WindowID.txt), and use it to embed four [`st`](http://st.suckless.org/) terminal instances inside `tabbed`, with titles from `1` to `4`, in ascending or descending order. I tried the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

xid=`tabbed -cd`
i=1

while [ $i -le $1 ]; do
        st -t $i -w $xid &
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

It works, but the `st`s are launched not in the sequence imposed by the `while` cycle: the order of tabs, in fact, is random.

1) They must all be background processes, but how to obtain the correct order for them?

2) How to obtain the same with CLI?

```
$ xid=`tabbed -cd` && (st -t '1' -w $xid & st -t '2' -w $xid & st -t '3' -w $xid & st -t '4' -w $xid &)
```

creates an apparent random order like the script.

Comment: Probably the order of the tabs depends on how fast the `st` background programs come to the point where the tab is added. There is no guarantee that the one you ran first will be the first at this point. You could try a `if [ $i -ne 1 ]; then sleep 1; fi` before `st -t $i -w $xid &`.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you, I tried and it works correctly; just, it is very slow. IIUC, there is some random time between when the `st` process is launched and when it actually appears as a tab. Do you think there is not a way to verify if it has correctly beeen added as a tab, before running the next `st`?

Comment: To speed things up, I tried with `sleep 0.25` (lower times cause again that random tab number order). But even `0.25` is too high, when several (4) tabs must be created.